# Can I find the PDF of $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$ by integrating $f_{xy}(x, y)$ along the line $y=x/z$?

Tags: probability

I am currently studying probability, and am trying to understand joint probability distributions. Namely, I am trying to figure out how to compute the pdf of a new random variable $Z$ where $Z=g(X,Y)$.

For example, imagine we have $g(X, Y) = \frac{X}{Y}$ and $Z = g(X, Y)$. Is it possible to determine the PDF of $Z$ using a line integral in the x-y plane?

I am working through this, and am currently getting answers that don't make any sense. Something tells me that this does not work, but it feels like it intuitively should work. I feel like I should be able to integrate $f_{xy}(x, y)$ along the line $y=x/z$ to find the value of $f_z(z)$, but, I can't get the correct answer using this method.

Does a method to compute a PDF like this make mathematical sense, or is what I am trying to do not mathematically valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may make use of the Fundamental Rule of Calculus.

$$\begin{align}f_Z(z)&=\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d z}\mathsf P(X/Y\leqslant z)\\&=\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d z}\Big(\mathsf P(Yz\leqslant X~, Y<0)+\mathsf P(X\leqslant Yz~, 0\leqslant Y)\Big)\\&=\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d z}\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{yz}^\infty f_{X,Y\!}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y+\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d z}\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{yz} f_{X,Y\!}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\&=\int_{-\infty}^0\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial z}\int_{yz}^\infty f_{X,Y\!}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y+\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial z}\int_{-\infty}^{yz} f_{X,Y\!}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\&=\int_{-\infty}^0 -y~f_{X,Y\!}(yz,y)\,\mathrm d y+\int_0^\infty y~ f_{X,Y\!}(yz,y)\,\mathrm d y\\&=\int_\Bbb R \lvert y\rvert~f_{X,Y\!}(yz,y)~\mathrm d y\end{align}$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you